# Understanding the JavaScript Error object

Tags: javascript, prototype

I wasn't sure about how properties like `message` work in the `Error` JavaScript object context, so I made a test:

```
var e = new Error('foo');

console.log(Object.keys(e)); // displays "[]"
```

And now:

```
var e = new Error();
e.message = 'foo';
console.log(Object.keys(e)); // displays "['message']"
```

I suppose that when a message is passed to the constructor, this field will belong to the `Error` object prototype, but I don't how if I could reproduce the same behavior with a class of mine to better understand:

```
function C(msg) {
  // **What to write here to make msg belong to the C prototype?**
}

var c = new C('foo');
console.log(Object.keys(c)); // **I would like it to display []**
```

My question is: how to simulate the Error message property behavior in my C class?

Comment: what is the question..?

Comment: The term for properties that don't show up in `for-in` loops and `Object.keys` is "non-enumerable".

Comment: You would `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e))`

Comment: console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)); has the name and message properties. it's part of the Error.prototype object

Comment: @BOSS: indeed but when I pass nothing to the constructor, "message" is no more defined in the prototype. That's this behavior I would like to understand and reproduce.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question, what's wrong with `function C(msg) { C.prototype.msg = msg }`>

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni C.prototype is not yet defined at the constructor time. Make a test :)

Comment: I did a test before posting that. I did another one right now: `function C(msg) { C.prototype.msg = msg }; var c = new C('test'); c.msg; // -> 'test'`

Comment: you were right, I read too fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to define a non-enumerable property:

```
function C(msg) {
    // you an use  enumerable: false  in the third argument, 
    // but it is false by default
    Object.defineProperty(this, "message", { value: msg });
}

var c = new C("hello");

console.log(Object.keys(c).length); // 0
console.log(c.message);             // hello
```

If you don't care about whether `message` is enumerable or not (it's not clear from your question), then you can use this ordinary approach:

```
function C(msg) {
    this.message = msg;
}

var c = new C("hello");

console.log(Object.keys(c).length); // 1
console.log(c.message);             // hello
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't really understand why Error's message (and probably name) is not enumerable, but your answer is the one I was expecting.

Comment: @Guid All properties on built-in objects described in [Chapter 15 of the ES5 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15), are writable, non-enumerable, and configurable, unless stated otherwise: _Every other property described in this clause has the attributes { [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: true } unless otherwise specified._